# me when I take down a standing pile by jumping on top?

Tags: american-football

When I see a standing pile or freinds trying to tackle another person I jusm on top and with me being the heaviest on the team it comes down, yet the refs pull me aside and scream at me not to do it, idk why or what penalty I could get for just helping out on takleing

Comment: What have your coaches said to you about this?

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is reckless, dangerous and stupid. Players underneath you could be seriously harmed or killed by it.

## Stop doing it or get out of the game.

The officials have a duty to safety of the players. That you don't understand this already, suggests you are playing at a very low level of the sport, where this duty is even more important, as the lack of skill compounds the effect of situations where accidental injury is likely.